# Python BadYieldError: yielded unknown object HTTPError('HTTP 599: Connection closed',)

Tags: python, return, tornado, yield

I want to know why in this function:

```
@tornado.gen.engine
def check_status_changes(netid, sensid):

    como_url = "".join(['http://131.114.52:44444/ztc?netid=', str(netid), \
               '&sensid=', str(sensid), '&start=-5s&end=-1s'])

    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url)

    if response.error:
        raise Exception(response.error)
```

when there's response.error, I obtain the title error... what I have to yield in order to catch the returned value in another function?

I would after do something like:

```
try:
        periodic = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(check_status_changes(netid, sensid), 5000)
        value = periodic.start()
        print("Secondo")
        print value
    except:
        print("Quarto")
        periodic.stop()
        self.finish()
        return
    else:
```

I don't know... I would just compare the returned value with another....

Thank you.

Comment: Why not raise an exception instead? Then handle the exception separately in the consumer of this generator.

Comment: How can I do? I can't raise a Bad Yield Exception...

Comment: Create your own exception? You can raise *any exception* you like.

Comment: raise Exception(response.error)

Comment: What is up with all this yielding btw.? Having yields and returns in one function does not look really great.

Comment: @RickyA: this is tornado's generator-based async engine. Yields and callbacks everywhere.

Comment: Mwaaa..., will become spaghetti code real soon. Anyway the returns/yields of this function should be consistent. Now it is either retuning nothing or yielding am error mssg (with an useless return stacked on top of it)

Comment: So... I have to remove the return? can you write me the answer with the code?

Comment: I raise the exception. But in the other function I have to put a try-catch statement? How I write this?

Comment: documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: Yeah! I'm just reading this document :D I edit the question..

Comment: I dont really get what you want to compare. If you want the response.error in the except clause you could do something like: `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: Ok, but I only want a way to divide the case I obtain the error from the case I obtain the right response from the server....

Comment: You just did that. If no error occurs everything in `try` block is executed. If an error occurs it breaks execution after `value = periodic.start()` and jumps to the `except` block

Comment: Ok after the raise exception now I obtain this error: `raise Exception(response.error)
Exception: HTTP 599: Connection closed`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27569/discussion-between-sharkbait-and-rickya)

Comment: What do you think of this bug? https://github.com/facebook/tornado/commit/351c3223f52124dadb135b629818cd5cec8a4065

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function has a `gen.engine` decorator, you can't return a value from inside it (not tornado related, you can't return a value inside a generator).

If you are trying to get a value out of that function -provided you are calling that on IOLoop-, that function should have a `callback` (callable) keyword argument as such:

```
@tornado.gen.engine
def check_status_changes(netid, sensid, callback=None):
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(do_your_thing)
    if response.error:
        raise response.error
    callback(response.body)  # this is how you make the value available to the
                             # caller; response.body is HTTPResponse specific iirc
```

Now you can call this function somewhere else as such:

```
# somewhere in a gen.engine decorated async method
body = yield tornado.gen.Task(check_status_changes, netid, sensid)
```

Comment: Yes, but if you see the second part of code, I would call the check_status_changes in a periodic callback. How can I do in this case? Your solution is good. Make the call periodic! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
raise tornado.gen.Return(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
        @gen.coroutine
        def get(self):
            http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
            http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
            response = yield http_client.fetch('http://localhost:1338/api/getDistinctGeoPositions/?durationInMinutes=9000')
            if response.error:
                print response.error
            self.finish(response.body)
```